# Fragmented MP4 freezes on ffplay after some time

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I won't take much time from you...

I am streaming a fragmented mp4 from ffmpeg with this command-line

```
ffmpeg  \
-f video4linux2  \
-video_size 640x480 \
-framerate 60 \
-i /dev/video0 \
-c:v h264_omx \
-b:v 500k \
-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov  \
-f mp4 udp://192.168.1.196:1234
```

Then on my host (the IP from above) I use a simple ffplay command-line

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer udp://0.0.0.0:1234
```

The results are pretty good with a latency of half a second.

The problem is that after, let's say, 30s, the video freezes but everything is still sending frames and receiving frames.

I discovered that at streaming time some frames are being dropped and being FMP4..... frames dropped may cause this?

I would like to know how to prevent this freezing because if I increase the fps to 90 (which reduces the latency to 350ms) the video freezes earlier (frames being dropped before)

Thanks

Comment: When you say "fragmented", do you mean you are streaming a segmented file, or that it may be actually fragmented on your drive? If the latter, have you tried "e4defrag" in Terminal?

Comment: why have you disabled buffering in the client? it seems like that might help.

Comment: @FrankThomas nobuffer only skips the buffer used to hold initial frames when the app is probing the input.

Comment: @Didier Well I am little newbie here on video streaming. I thought that streaming from the pi camera using ffmpeg and enabling the movflag _fragkey_ will convert the output mp4 into a fragmented mp4

Comment: @Gyan then ffplay still has buffer after the start?

Comment: In one of the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177797/what-exactly-is-fragmented-mp4fmp4-how-is-it-different-from-normal-mp4), it says that you can set the interval in between each segment you broadcast. There could lie part of your answer: if the interval set by default (in case you haven't set it yourself) is too high, you might find a lag or freeze between frames, at a regular interval.